# Why is this option's price so out of line?

Tags: options, call-options

This option's price seems completely insane:

TCF Jan 17 2020 22.5 Call (TCF200117C00022500)

[image: Screenshot from TD Ameritrade]

Why is this option's price so far out?

Answer (score 1):

Chemical Financial merger with TCF Financial during the summer.  The old TCF options were adjusted and became TCF1 options.  One contract of TCF1 now represents  50 shares of (New) TCF Financial Corporation common shares and cash in lieu of 0.81 fractional TCF shares.

Sorry but I can't provide the link for you because I'm registered with the OCC and for some unknown reason, any searches I do there result in my real name being included in the web address.

OCC MEMO #45266

- DATE: JUNE 26, 2019
- SUBJECT: TCF FINANCIAL CORPORATION ANTICIPATED ADJUSTMENT-
- OPTION SYMBOL: TCF
- NEW SYMBOL: TCF1
- CONTRACT ADJUSTMENT
- DATE: Effective the opening of the business day after the merger is consummated. Contract adjustment is anticipated to occur during the late third or early fourth quarter of 2019.
- OPTION SYMBOL: TCF changes to TCF1
- STRIKE DIVISOR: 1
- CONTRACTS
- MULTIPLIER: 1
- NEW MULTIPLIER: 100 (e.g., a premium of 1.50 yields $150; a strike of 25.00 yields $2500.00)
- NEW DELIVERABLE PER CONTRACT:
- 1) 50 (New) TCF Financial Corporation (TCF) common chares
- 2) Cash in lieu of 0.81 fractional TCF shares

Comment: I understand what you're referring to and I've seen this with other stocks such as SIRI (Sirius XM) which after merging with Pandora now has SIRI1 options. However, those are marked as nonstandard options and they indicate it as well with the '1' suffix. This option does not have the '1' suffix and it is a standard option, not nonstandard. So I think this is a different scenario.

Comment: I can't speak to how  your data source displays this.  So let's reason it out.  The TCF1 option requires 50 shares plus .81 PIL per share.  That's $42.75 / 2 *100 plus $42.75 * .81 which equals $2,172.13 which divided by the 100 multiplier gives a current value of $21.72.  It's quite reasonable that a one month on a $22.50 call with the stock at $21.72 would have a quote of $0.70 x $1.00 .  The quote chain at Optionistics shows the TCF1 Jan $22.50 call with a last price of 70 cents, agreeing with your quote.  I'll double check this tomorrow when my trading platform is open.

Comment: @notmySOaccount - Fri AM: The info on my platform indicates that this is an adjusted option with delivery of 50 shares of TCF and $0.3482 cash.  It also indicates that the closing price of the underlying yesterday was $21.72 which is identical to the numbers that I calculated last night.  FWIW, avoid adjusted options whenever possible, especially in positions that are combined  with standard options :->)

Comment: Thanks, I do avoid adjusted options but there is nothing in my data source (TD Ameritrade + their API) indicating this option is adjusted. There are 3 fields that usually indicate it. There is a field for "nonstandard" which is false for this option. There are two deliverables fields which are also blank for this option. However, I think your answer is correct and I've upvoted it along with your subsequent comments, which leads me to a follow up Q: do you know of any public data source indicating that this is a TCF1 option? I'd like to cross-check other options against it as well.

Comment: @notmySOaccount - Sorry but  I don't understand your question. What else would it be other than a TCF1 option? If you go to OPTIONISTICS.COM then click Option Chains and enter TCF, it will bring up the option chain which includes TCF and TCF1 options. The same holds true for option quotes at CBOE.com.  Neither one gives adjustment details.  I got that from my platform.  Either you're missing something at Ameritrade (like clicking a box that says Include "Non Standard Options") or they are not providing accurate data.

Comment: I do not understand the confusion either. "What else would it be other than a TCF1 option?" It shows up as a TCF option in TD Ameritrade. Hence this question. I'm explicitly excluding nonstandard options. " Neither one gives adjustment details. I got that from my platform." - That was the answer to the question, so clearly you did understand it. Thanks again for your help although I don't understand why you are suddenly being so aggressive.

Comment: Also, I visited Optionistics.com after you mentioned it earlier but I can't see any TCF1 options there at all. When I enter TCF, I can see only TCF options. Hence my follow up question. In fact, I still cannot see any TCF1 options on optionistics.com now.

Comment: I just went to Optionistics  and the TCF1 options are displayed for January.  Look for  FILTER CRITERIA in the top middle of the page.  Make sure that in the lower one which is titled EXPIRATION, that the right slide bar is pushed far enough to the right so that it includes and displays January 2020 options.  You can also view them at the CBOE site at http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quote-table (enter TCF as the symbol)